# Sql server 2008 integration services - How to get file from web

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to create a integration service to regularly get file from a web link. Flat File connection manager only allow me to read from local file, but not from web. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest adding a in a script task to bring the file locally then pick it up with the flat file connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script task like seen in this article http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx.  Then connect to the file using the file connection manager.  You are going to need a similar file to the flat file gathered from the web to do the initial settings.

Comment: I've done it using script component myself as well. Seems that is simplest way. Thanks